# Python reading records from a json file and writing to two separate json files

Tags: json, python-2.7, twitter

I have a twitter json file and I'm and trying to separate the English and French tweets into two separate files. I'm using Python 2.7 with the following code:

```
import json

with open('tweets.json', 'r') as f:

with open('english.json', 'w') as enF:
  with open('french.json', 'w') as frF:

    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)

        if tweet["lang"] == "en":
             json.dump(tweet, enF, sort_keys=True)
        elif tweet["lang"] == "fr":
             json.dump(tweet, frF, sort_keys=True)
```

This produces the two separate json files, one having English tweets and the other French, which I have checked. The original file has one tweet per line. The english.json and the french.json files have just a single line of all the tweets. Not sure if that will be a problem, not even confident that this is correct. So I passed the english.json again through this code (obviously I changed the name of the file) and it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jack\Desktop\twitClean\j4.py", line 10, in <module>
tweet = json.loads(line)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 367, in decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 4926 - line 1 column 691991 (char 4925 - 691990)
```

I've been working on this for the past three days, and have come up with nothing. Can anyone please help and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you do `tweet = json.loads(line)`, you are assuming that there is one json-like element per line. Which is likely the reason why you get the error `ValueError: Extra data:[...]`. Instead, you should read the json file as such, e.g. using `json.loads(f)`, where `f` is the opened json file object, i.e. `open('tweets.json', 'r')`. Then you could explore it. See the above answer. Does it work ?

Comment: This works to give the new files. When I run one of the new files through this code it still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you drop the `s` from `json.loads` ? Then you will use the right methode to handle file-like object, *i.e.*, `json.load`, **with  no s**. It appears you did not if you get the same error. See the above answer.

Comment: `json.load` gives error:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0):

What about loading the json file as such

```
with open('tweets.json', 'r') as f:
    tweets_dict = json.load(f)
```

Then, given that the python-native representation of a json is a dictionnary, you can iter over it and build your french and english related dictionnaries as well. I mean, doing

```
fr_dict, en_dict, ot_dict = {}, {}, {}
for id_,tweet in tweets_dict.items():
    if tweet['lang'] == 'fr':
        fr_dict[id_] = tweet
    elif tweet['lang'] == 'en':
        en_dict[id_] = tweet
    else:
        ot_dict[id_] = tweet 

with open('french.json', 'w') as frF:
    json.dump(fr_dict, frF, sort_keys=True) 

with open('english.json', 'w') as enF:
    json.dump(en_dict, enF, sort_keys=True)

with open('other.json', 'w') as otF:
    json.dump(ot_dict, otF, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Just tried this and this does not run:                                                                                                         
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/LearnPython/st.py", line 4, in <module>
    tweets_dict = json.loads(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @user1907031. See update. *Mea culpa* To work with files and not with strings, it is `json.load` instead of `json.loads`. You only have to drop the `s` to use the right methode.

Comment: Gives error:     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @user1907031. I guess you still get this error because you still continue to loop over `f`, *i.e*, when you do `for line in f`. Doing so makes `line` be a string, whence the error when you then do `tweet = json.load(line)`.  You **cannot** read the file like so. And you will have to consider it for what it is and read it as such. In the first code-block of my answer, I show you how to turn all the content of the file named `'tweets.json'` into a python-dictionnary you can then explore doing a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  Unfortunately, being only a python hacker I cannot solve this using python. I'm sure there must be a way using python. So if someone else needs such a solution here it is.The solution I found was using jq as follows:
`cat jsonfile | jq '. | select(.lang=="en")' > savefile`

Obviously using this code the jsonfile has to be read twice as I need the English and French tweets in separate files.